# Insert query using CTE in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression, sql-insert

I want to insert into one table from another table using a CTE. I have tried to put semicolon before `with`, but it's not working.

This is my query :

```
INSERT INTO [autoFIE2].[dbo].[tbl_article_type_parent_child] ([art_typ_parent_index], [art_typ_child_index])
WITH article_type_list AS
(
    SELECT 
       art_typ_child_index, art_typ_parent_index
    FROM
       [autoFIE2].[dbo].[tbl_article_type_parent_child]  
    WHERE 
       art_typ_parent_index IS NULL 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
       a.art_typ_child_index, a.art_typ_parent_index
    FROM
       [autoFIE2].[dbo].[tbl_article_type_parent_child] A 
    INNER JOIN 
       article_type_list as AL ON a.art_typ_parent_index = al.art_typ_child_index
    WHERE 
       a.art_typ_parent_index IS NOT NULL)
SELECT * 
FROM article_type_list;
```

Error while executing this statement :-

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'.
>
> Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking
>   context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a
>   semicolon.

What should I do to insert this hierarchical data into another table. Any suggestion ?

Comment: You don't need to wrap the sub-query up with a CTE

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Declare the `cte` first, then the insert from select list from cte:

```
;WITH article_type_list AS
(
    SELECT 
       art_typ_child_index, art_typ_parent_index
    FROM
       [autoFIE2].[dbo].[tbl_article_type_parent_child]  
    WHERE 
       art_typ_parent_index IS NULL 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
       a.art_typ_child_index, a.art_typ_parent_index
    FROM
       [autoFIE2].[dbo].[tbl_article_type_parent_child] A 
    INNER JOIN 
       article_type_list as AL ON a.art_typ_parent_index = al.art_typ_child_index
    WHERE 
       a.art_typ_parent_index IS NOT NULL
)
INSERT INTO [autoFIE2].[dbo].[tbl_article_type_parent_child] 
([art_typ_parent_index], [art_typ_child_index])
SELECT * FROM article_type_list;
```